# Jasper Subreport is not loooks same when I import it into main report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I had an issue with the output of the subreport. When I try to run it as separately then it's giving me a proper and expected output but when I try to add it into the main report then it's giving me a default and also somehow size of the output is also changed.

**Code of Subreport(overallScore.jrxml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="overallScore" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9589e36d-383b-450c-98c8-0530ee0af2b8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Misbar"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from risk_survey_score where score_level='RISK_SURVEY']]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.Float">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score_level" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="section_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="user_risk_survey_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="60" width="140" height="150" forecolor="#F2C216" backcolor="#121111" uuid="c7828afa-9951-4a65-8fce-e120c647f0b5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <cvc:customvisualization xmlns:cvc="http://www.jaspersoft.com/cvcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jaspersoft.com/cvcomponent http://www.jaspersoft.com/cvcomponent/component.xsd">
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="script" value="radial_progress.min.js"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="css" value="radial_progress.css"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="module" value="radial_progress"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="value">
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{score}]]></valueExpression>
                    </cvc:itemProperty>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="target" value="100"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="valueFormat" value=".1%"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="autoFit" value="true"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="fgColor" value="#F44B00"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="fgOpacity" value="1"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="showBackground" value="true"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="bgColor" value="#F44B00"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="bgOpacity" value="0.2"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="ringThickness" value="4.0"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="ringPadding" value="4.0"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="maxRings" value="0"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="hPadding" value="10"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="vPadding" value="10"/>
                    <cvc:itemProperty name="animation" value="true"/>
                </cvc:customvisualization>
            </componentElement>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement x="148" y="40" width="412" height="180" uuid="b597c0b8-7c69-4bf5-a08a-db009b110d93">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{score} > 8]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/hp/Desktop/Pirimid/RiskSurveyImage.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="148" height="30" forecolor="#08095C" uuid="a469994b-d2a0-452d-924b-3914703eb204"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Overall Score]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Code of Subreport 2 (riskApetite.jrxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="riskApetite" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1f7988e9-35f8-489b-991a-c7990c85b224">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Misbar"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from risk_survey_score]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.Float">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score_level" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="section_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="user_risk_survey_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="268" splitType="Stretch">
            <meterChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement key="" x="72" y="1" width="410" height="200" uuid="542c2956-912f-4cc1-abe1-341029ed0c81">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.element.name" value="Risk Apetite"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <chartTitle color="#08095C">
                        <font fontName="Serif" size="19"/>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["Risk Apetite"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle>
                        <font isItalic="true"/>
                    </chartSubtitle>
                    <chartLegend position="Bottom">
                        <font size="11"/>
                    </chartLegend>
                </chart>
                <valueDataset>
                    <dataset resetType="Report"/>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{score}]]></valueExpression>
                </valueDataset>
                <meterPlot shape="pie" tickInterval="50.0" meterColor="#F44B00" needleColor="#08095C" tickColor="#FFFFFF">
                    <plot orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    <valueDisplay color="#211FA3">
                        <font size="0"/>
                    </valueDisplay>
                    <dataRange>
                        <lowExpression><![CDATA[0]]></lowExpression>
                        <highExpression><![CDATA[100]]></highExpression>
                    </dataRange>
                    <meterInterval label="Willingness" color="#B45B2D" alpha="1.0">
                        <dataRange>
                            <lowExpression><![CDATA[0]]></lowExpression>
                            <highExpression><![CDATA[50]]></highExpression>
                        </dataRange>
                    </meterInterval>
                    <meterInterval label="Ability" color="#DE7C3A" alpha="1.0">
                        <dataRange>
                            <lowExpression><![CDATA[50]]></lowExpression>
                            <highExpression><![CDATA[100]]></highExpression>
                        </dataRange>
                    </meterInterval>
                </meterPlot>
            </meterChart>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="23" y="219" width="520" height="49" forecolor="#08095C" uuid="744fc920-8186-495c-9b9c-b4c9b73951b6"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[You result shows a well-balanced wiliness and ability to take risk. This indicates not only you have the ability to take risk but the desire to take risk.]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Main report in which I imported aove two subreport.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FinalTestReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f9a10419-b326-4377-a902-f0228d6644c9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Misbar"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from risk_survey_score;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.Float">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="score_level" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="score_level"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="section_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="section_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <field name="user_risk_survey_id" class="java.util.UUID">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="user_risk_survey_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="risk_survey_score"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement x="140" y="480" width="402" height="310" uuid="16b7b8e5-0a66-4b01-89ea-38a33f2ba1a4"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/hp/Desktop/Pirimid/RoboAdvisory/frontend/lowopacityImage.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="0" width="268" height="57" backcolor="#F44B00" uuid="c4590c8e-6b26-4be4-859d-bbb21c30cec7"/>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="22" y="0" width="226" height="57" backcolor="#08095C" uuid="d5f66796-e34f-4421-93fd-27bd2a9232a9"/>
            </rectangle>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="49" y="10" width="170" height="47" forecolor="#332E01" backcolor="#08095C" uuid="714c42f2-9014-460d-b3ce-a60f5dc69070"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/hp/Desktop/Pirimid/RoboAdvisory/frontend/misbar-frontend/src/assets/logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="50"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="21" y="30" width="554" height="24" forecolor="#08095C" backcolor="#08095C" uuid="3b7b3eee-04ed-4c46-b133-a22415eda242"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="08e28acc-bfd2-43b2-a43b-ced62da43b05"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b4d63e7e-e327-4549-9486-96ae5aba2d89"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="170478a3-202b-4918-b9b5-ca19f7deb600"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="528" y="0" width="26" height="24" backcolor="#F44B00" uuid="6eca8eb2-c6d9-434f-a207-9d9548261f1e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#F44B00"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="490" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="-20" y="30" width="41" height="40" uuid="54f9d70d-7ebb-4c80-a3e7-6d23d941331d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="score">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{score}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["/Misbar/overallScore/overallScore.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="22" y="10" width="148" height="30" forecolor="#08095C" uuid="182ce2a2-5464-4769-896d-baadfcb32e7e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Overall Score]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="230" width="200" height="100" uuid="bf6266f8-3739-4557-9a5c-4a2a1a6c24c1"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["/Misbar/riskApetite/riskApetite.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second subreport I have no idea.
For the first one that is smaller, I think you are accumulating the margins of the main and the subreport.
Basically you need to remove the margins from the subreport and let only the ones form the main report.